# Where do I get the x11 driver for linux on Centos 7.9 with Nvidia 5.20 driver support?

Tags: centos, x11, drivers, nvidia, repository

I used to get the x11 driver from elrepo, however now it appears that it's behind what I am required to install https://pkgs.org/search/?q=nvidia-x11-drv  and is stuck at 5.15, where as when I install everything else, it's 5.20.  I can't figure out where I'm supposed to get x11 stuff that actually works?  I tried running nvidia-xconfig, then rebooting, crossing my fingers that maybe Nvidia decided to just package it with everything else this time, but I think that actually just caused my computer to freeze on boot? (just stuck at blinking cursor claiming "Starting SYSV: Splunk indexer service...e osad daemon.tions.")

Comment: Useless comment : CentOS 7.9 ? that is based on linux-3.10 ? Well… I would personally refrain from installing most recent nvidia proprietary drivers on such old kernel.

Comment: @MC68020 I don't have a choice, this is the only distro I can use.

Comment: You might not be able to use the Nvidia drivers then. Or you will have to build your own modern kernel for your old distro, and lose the stability guarantee that is the reason you have to use that old distro. Possibly also actively breaks the stuff that forces you to use that distro.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the issue came down to me trying to install an update to cuda before doing a sudo yum update.  By not using yum update, the DKMS modules did not incorperate the new driver into the kernel.  yum update would have done the proper dkms nvidia module install prior to all the other Nvidia drivers. After uninstalling all nvidia packages, and then running the nvidia dkms stuff first, everything worked fine.